# Get OrmLite database column name from property name

Tags: servicestack

Let's say I have this class:

```cs
public class FooBar
{
    public long Id {get; set;}
    public string BarFoo {get; set;}
}
```

OrmLite when using postgresql will create table name `foo_bar` and columns `id`, and `bar_foo`.

I can get the table name for use in a custom query like so:

```cs
db.ExecuteSql($"INSERT INTO {db.GetTableName<SomeOtherClass>()}(bar_foo) SELECT bar_foo FROM {db.GetTableName<FooBar>()}");
```

If the naming convention changes or the property is re-named then the query breaks because the column `bar_foo` is defined as a string.

How do I define the column names in the same fashion I am defining the table names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the table & column names from the dialect provider, e.g:

```
var dialect = db.Dialect(); //older API db.GetDialectProvider()
```

By their name where it will use the configured NamingStrategy:

```
var tableName = dialect.GetQuotedTableName(nameof(FooBar));
var columnName = dialect.GetQuotedColumnName(nameof(FooBar.BarFoo));
```

By OrmLite's model & field definition where it will also make use of any RDBMS `[Alias]` customizations defined on the model:

```
var modelDef = typeof(FooBar).GetModelMetadata();
var fieldDef = modelDef.GetFieldDefinition(nameof(FooBar.BarFoo));

var tableName = dialect.GetQuotedTableName(modelDef);
var columnName = dialect.GetQuotedColumnName(modelDef,fieldDef);
```